# Send and consume message by one connection

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there a way to do this? My case: there are connections "A", "B", and "C", that subscribed to the topic with name "Topic 1". "A" sends a message to the topic and it doesn't receive it. "B" and "C" receive this message. If "C" sends a message to topic then it's "A" and "B" who get the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `true` for the `noLocal` parameter when you create your consumer.

For example, the [`javax.jms.MessageConsumer#createConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createConsumer-javax.jms.Destination-java.lang.String-boolean-) method has an overloaded version that takes a `javax.jms.Destination`, a `String`, and a `boolean`. If you specify `true` for the `boolean` (i.e. the `noLocal` parameter) then messages published using that same connection won't be consumed. The JavaDoc says this about the `noLocal` parameter:

> The `noLocal` argument is for use when the destination is a topic and the session's connection is also being used to publish messages to that topic. If `noLocal` is set to `true` then the `MessageConsumer` will not receive messages published to the topic by its own connection. The default value of this argument is `false`. If the destination is a queue then the effect of setting `noLocal` to `true` is not specified.